# Advance in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I tag photos with key words and when view that photo after click on the links, i want to retrieve the link to the collection of photos which has same key word.I have stored the tag keyword by using comma separated.Can any one please suggest me how to get that data?

Comment: can you show sample records with your desired result?

Comment: Why would you store a comma-separated list in mysql?

Comment: @ExplosionPills many beginners don't understand the "relational" part of a relational database.

Comment: Learn 1NF, 2NF and 3NF before doing things more complex.

Comment: In PHP *explode* the list, create a new table *keywords* `(photoId, keyword)` and insert each keyword for that photoId. Create an index on  *keyword*, the search will be faster.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to use a query that takes advantage of the [LIKE clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like):

```
SELECT * FROM `photo` WHERE `keywords` LIKE "%' . $keyword . '%"
```

Keep in mind however, that a comma-separated list is NOT the best practice for doing this. By keeping it in this list, you take up more space than necessary, slowing down transfer time and taking up redundant space.

You should ideally have another table handle tags (and link the tag keywords in yet another table) and simply [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) the tables to get your results.

Comment: Just to add to your already fine answer, [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) is the keyword here.

Comment: Thank you so much for you comments. sql= 'SELECT photo_upload.id_photo as pho_id,files.filename as file,photo_upload.photo_name as name,user.user_name as user,user.user_id as u_id,
        photo_upload.tag_id as tag,photo_upload.id_photo as id from photo_upload INNER JOIN user ON user.user_id =photo_upload.user_id
INNER JOIN tag_topic ON tag_topic.tagging_id =photo_upload.tag_id
INNER JOIN files ON files.id =photo_upload.id WHERE tag_topic.tagging_id=\''.$tag.'\' '; As i used comma separeated tagid in photoupload table i can't execute this sql.

Comment: Thanks all I have done this using LIKE :)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has a function `FIND_IN_SET()` that can be used for this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE FIND_IN_SET("tag", keywords) > 0
```